# Count pixels of a black and white image (OpenCV / C++ )

Tags: c++, opencv

I am a beginner to opencv / C ++ and would like your help with a problem that seems simple. As an example, I have this image:

[image: image example]

... And would disregard the background, which will always be white, and the image is always black and white, leaving only the cloud to be able to count three things:

1. The number of pixels of the figure (cloud only, disregarding the background).
2. The number of white pixels. (cloud only)
3. The number of black pixels. (cloud only)

I know that to achieve 2, with a subtraction with it the 3rd.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very simple method

- Count the black pixels (3)
- Flood-fill with black starting at any corner
- Count the number of remaining white pixels (2)
- Add results (2) and (3) to get (1)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can use `cv::countNonZero(img)` to count non-black pixels. Thus you can use `(img.rows * img.cols) - cv::countNonZero(img)` to count black pixels.

Now, try the following: First, count the black pixels. Then try to use morphological opening to remove those white blobs inside the clould. Afterwards, count the black pixels again. Now you can substract the first count from the second one and you'll get the amount of white pixels inside those blobs.

However, this method will not be accurate, because the morphological opening will also alter the cloud a bit on the outside. An alternative would be the method suggested in an other answer, to use flood fill to fill the surrounding white pixels with black.

Morphological opening works like this by the way:

```
cv::Mat element = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE, cv::Size(2 * openingRadius + 1, 2 * openingRadius + 1));
cv::morphologyEx(mat, mat, cv::MORPH_OPEN, element);
```

Or, with cuda:

```
cv::Mat element = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE, cv::Size(2 * openingRadius + 1, 2 * openingRadius + 1));
cv::cuda::createMorphologyFilter(cv::MORPH_OPEN, CV_8UC1, element)->apply(gpuMat, gpuMat);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to count to find black pixel in an image.Apply same logic for counting white pixels.

```
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{

Mat img = imread("/home/jordan/opencv/Test/edge_detection/img2.bmp",0);
cout<<"cols= "<<img.cols<<"row= "<<img.rows<<"\n";
int i,j,count=0;
for(i=0;i<img.cols;i++)
{
for(j=0;j<img.rows;j++)
{
int k=img.at<uchar>(j,i);
if(k==0)
{  
count++;
cout<<"col="<<i<<"row="<<j<<"k= "<< k<<"\t\n";
}
}
} 
cout<<"count="<<count<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: I think counting the black pixels is easier using `(img.rows * img.cols) - cv::countNonZero(img)`